# Perfect hashing function in a hash table implementation of a sparse matrix class

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm currently implementing a sparse matrix for my matrix library - it will be a hash table. I already implemented a dense matrix as a nested vector, and since I'm doing it just to learn new stuff, I decided that my matrices will be multi-dimensional (not just a 2D table of numbers, but also cubes, tesseracts, etc).

I use an index type which holds n numbers of type `size_t`, n being a number of dimensions for this particular index. Index of dimension `n` may be used only as an address of an element in a matrix of appropriate dimension. It is simply a tuple with implicit constructor for easy indexing, like `Matrix[{1,2,3}]`.

My question is centered around the hashing function I plan on using for my sparse matrix implementation. I think that the function is always minimal, but is perfect only up to a certain point - to the point of `size_t` overflow, or an overflow of intermediate operation of the hashing function (they are actually `unsigned long long`). Sparse matrices have huge boundaries, so it's practically guaranteed to overflow at some point (see below).

What the hashing function does is assign consecutive numbers to matrix elements as follows:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ...]^T //transposed 1-dimensional matrix

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9 //2-dimensional matrix
```

and so on. Unfortunately, I'm unable show you the ordering for higher order matrices, but I hope that you get the idea - the value increases top to bottom, left to right, back to front (for cube matrices), etc.

The hashing function is defined like this:

`value = x1+d1*x2+d1*d2*x3+d1*d2*d3*x3+...+d1*d2*d3*...*d|n-1|*xn`

where:

- x1...xn are index members - row, column, height, etc - {x1, x2, x3,
  ..., xn}
- d1...d|n-1| are matrix boundary dimensions - one past the end of matrix in the appropriate direction

I'm actually using a recursive form of this function (simple factoring, but complexity becomes O(n) instead of O(n^2)):

`value = x1+d1(x2+d2(x3+d3(...(x|n-1|+d|n-1|(xn))...)))`

I'm assuming that elements will be distributed randomly (uniform) across the matrix, but the bucket number is `hash(key) mod numberOfBuckets`, so it is practically guaranteed to have collisions despite the fact, that the function is perfect.

1. Is there any way to exploit the features of my hash function in order to minimize collisions?
2. How should I choose the load factor? Should I leave the choice to the user? Is there any good default value for this case?
3. Is the hash table actually a good solution for this problem? Are there any other data structures that guarantee average O(1) complexity given that I can roll the index into  a number and a number into an index (mind the `size_t` overflow)? I am aware of different ways to store a sparse matrix, but I want to try the DOK way first.